# CSS arc/circle not correct - Circle

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, css-animations

I am trying to draw an arc by using css canvas.
reference,

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp

BY using this trying on jsfiddle. But, it is not working as expected.

```
enter code here
```

[JS Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/z4y7sd1j/1/)

What mistake I did it here.

Comment: Better documentation is found on MDN: [`arc`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc), [`<canvas>`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#sizing_the_canvas_using_css_versus_html).

Comment: Understood , the  Width and height ratio is 2:1 , This working, Thanks.